# Does android-support-v4 jar will be bundled with the android application in which it is referred while compilation?

Tags: android

I have created an application on android, referring the "android-support-v4.jar" while compiling my application, so I want to know whether the generated apk will be bundled with the "android-support-v4.jar" or not?, If it gets bundled with the jar file then how can I ensure whether it is bundled or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be bundled.

The classes you use from `android-support-v4.jar` have to be part of your `.apk` in the end. If they are not your app will crash because it refers to code that does not exist. If the app works you have successfully included it.

Edit: there is no .jar in the apk. The support classes are directly embedded with your classes into `classes.dex`.

Comment: I have unzipped my apk, but could not find the “android-support-v4.jar”

Comment: Please let me know why I am unable to find compile time referrened .jar file after unzipping the apk file.

Comment: oops, you are right, the content of the support jar is not included as jar but directly into `classes.dex` which is suddenly 250kb bigger.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, can you please also let me know whether we can re-compile the jar "android-support-v4.jar" by getting the source code and its dependencies for compilation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library I guess