# How to add support-v4.jar javadoc into my project?

Tags: android

I have created a project and the support-v4.jar is already inside the libs and dependency.(It this normal? Cause I know people were trying to import the .jar manually).
But when I hovered my mouse over the class it said the javadoc doesn't exist. How do I solve this problem?? I created the project and if that comes with the support-v4.jar already, why isn't the javadoc?

Comment: support jar does not come with javadoc.

Comment: How to add support-v4.jar javadoc into my project then?

Comment: You can go through this post for adding javadoc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library

Comment: I try this:

 From the Java build path / libraries tab, expand android-support-v4.jar, highlight "Source attachment", click "Edit...", "External Folder..." then point to (android-sdk)\extras\android\support\v4.

doesn't work, although the .jar is attach to the source but the same message displayed when i hover my mouse on fragment class

Comment: And If I create a new one the source attachment is non modifiable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found some javadoc [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r6). I downloaded support-v4-r6-javadoc.jar and it works.