# How to attach source to Google Drive API or `Android Private Library` in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api

I've installed the *Drive API* using the `Add Google APIs...` menu option.
When manually drilling into any one of the jars under *Drive API*, the source code opens ok.

But manually drilling into the same jar under `Android Private Libraries` results in a "Source not found".

[image: project view]

So when using `open Declaration (F3)` for example, I get the "Source not found" page.

The build system links all the jars using a library called `Android Private Libraries`.

I could not find a way to attach source or documentation to the Drive API.

[image: attach source dialog]

All the options to attach anything are disabled.

Any advice?

Comment: Note the answer of andr in this topic :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a way...
I moved the "Drive API" library above "Android Private Libraries" in the "Order and Export" dialog of the Build Configuration window.
Hope it helps someone...