# How to add source of 'Android Private Libraries' to ADT eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I try to see source of source android-support-v4.jar and get:
"The jar of this class file belongs to container and 'Android Private Libraries' "
[image: Android Private Libraries]

Where to obtain and attach 'Android Private Libraries' source?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many question on that. 
Basically the `android-support-v4.jar` need to be in `Referenced Libraries` by right click, `Build Path`.., `Add to Path`. Then in `Referenced Libraries`, right click `properties` on `android-support-v4` and set the sources.

Taken from [How do I attach the Android Support Library source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library) and 
[How to attach source to Google Drive API or `Android Private Library` in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723852/how-to-attach-source-to-google-drive-api-or-android-private-library-in-eclipse) . Please go through the answers. They'll help you.

Comment: This did not work for me. I still get that error message. Do I need to restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 13):

You also need to make sure that the "Android Private Libraries" is ranked lower in the "Order and Export" tab of your project's "Java Build Path" preferences.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me! You have to put "Android Private Libraries" at the bottom. Thanks!