# How to add source + javadoc for android-support-v7?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I added to my project support library android-support-v7-appcompat, but I can't add source and javadoc for it.

I downloaded https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master package with source and in Eclipse I set Source attachment to v7/appcompat/, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

E: my solution is, I have two projects in Eclipse "android-support-v7-appcompat" (original lib from android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat) and "android-support-v7-appcompat-src" (src from android.googlesource.com) and when I compile release version, so I used original lib and for debug I used src from googlesource.com.

PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 9):

I was able to attach the source based on advice from [How do I attach the Android Support Library source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library).

Here's what I did:

First, clone the source repository and get whatever version corresponds to the released library (which I guessed):

1. git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support
2. cd support
3. git checkout android-4.3.1_r1

Next, in Eclipse:

1. Right-click project and choose *Properties*.
2. Select *Java Build Path*
3. Select the *Libraries* tab
4. Add External JARs > YourProject/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar (I know your project had already referenced to it but don't worry, just add it again).
5. Expand jar and attach Source to the External Jar: WhereverYouHaveTheSource/support/appcompat
6. Switch to the "Order and Export" tab, move the external jar above the "Android Dependencies"

Answer (score 8):

Or the same using @andr answer to [How do I attach the Android Support Library source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library)

```
git clone https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support android_sources_folder
```

add `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.properties` file into libs (next to android-support-v7-appcompat.jar) with content

```
src=D:\\android_sources_folder\\platform_frameworks_support\\v7\\appcompat\\src
```

close and reopen project

Comment: I was unable to make the solution by Johnson work so I turned to your answer and it works great. Thanks. For everyone else, I just added "android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.properties" in my app_compat project. It contains the values: `doc=/home/sufian/Apps/eclipse/android-sdk-linux/docs/reference/
src=/home/sufian/Android Open Source/support/v7/appcompat/src/`.

Comment: Also note, guys, if multiple libraries have **android-support-v4.jar** file then you need to have **android-support-v4.jar.properties** against each. I needed this to have my Javadocs and Sources work once again.

Answer (score 6):

Sources for appcompat-v7 are available within "API21/Sources for Android SDK" package which can be downloaded with SDK Manager, the path is `\sdk\sources\android-21\android\support\v7\`

Android Studio will allow you to browse lib source code when you point this dir as appcompat-v7 source dir root.