# Where can I download the source code of support library v7 of android?

Tags: android, android-source

I'd like to download the source code of both support library v4 and v7

but it seems like that in SDK Manager only the source code of Android itself can be found.

So where to download the support library source code? A zip file is better

======

Found source code of v4, but not v7

Comment: I don't think it's open source

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Support Library (v4). Getting the source and attaching it to the library/jar in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library). v7 will be located in a similar path.

Comment: I can't find the source code of v7

Comment: How is this off topic?  The guys is asking for source code to help debug his code.

Answer (score 5):

You can find it in [the support repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git).

Answer (score 4):

You already have it, if you downloaded the support package through the SDK manager. Navigate to your sdk folder:

```
<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/src
<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/src
<sdk>/extras/android/support/v13/src
```

Comment: There are 3 folders in v7/ , appcompt is what I what, but the src directory of of appcompt, I got only a .readme file

Comment: You're right, and the readme files says "There is technically no source, but the src folder is necessary to ensure that the build system works." I've never looked in there -- it appears not to be open source.

Answer (score 3):

The (Java) source for all the support libraries is nowadays in the same folder as the standard Android source code, that is, in `<android-sdk>\sources\android-XX\`. In particular, the `<android-sdk>\sources\android-XX\android\support` contains the full `android.support` package source code, which comprises all the support libraries.

For example:

- [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html), part of the "base" Support Library, is in `<android-sdk>\sources\android-21\android\support\v4\app\FragmentManager.java`.
- [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), part of the v7 appcompat library, is in `<android-sdk>\sources\android-21\android\support\v7\app\ActionBarActivity.java`.
- Same for cardview, mediarouter, &c.

Comment: Unfortunately the platform's source is not updated when there are support library releases.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here. Have to git clone the source code from google source code server:

[Cannot find Android support libraries source code (v4, v7 & v13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278664/cannot-find-android-support-libraries-source-code-v4-v7-v13)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find it on github. Try this link or Google it ;)

https://github.com/mastro/android-support-library-archive

Comment: There is no source code for v7 there

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible via this github repository:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/
```