# Android Studio: How to see sources for android support v4 and v7?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

In Android Studio support library `appcompat` (for ActionBar) is defined as Gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

That resolves to get v4 as well.

How to see source when clicking to into classes?

e.g. `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

Currently Android Studio says

> // IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
>   // Implementation of methods is not available

For ADT it was [How to add source + javadoc for android-support-v7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298638/how-to-add-source-javadoc-for-android-support-v7)

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718753/how-to-download-dependency-sources-for-gradle-project-in-idea and http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the above research done by Paul Verest...

IDE: Android studio 1.3.2

It is a 2-step process: Consider this sample build.gradle

1) Add the following to your build.gradle (Module:app) - search the 2 //Add comments below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'idea' //Add

android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.mycompany.android.myapp"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}

//Add
idea {
      module {
          downloadJavadoc = true
          downloadSources = true
      }
  }
```

2) Rebuild project.

After this point if you want to see source in Android Studio, it will pull up the source *.java instead of decompiled *.class

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Setu for [hint](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html). As I already had all sources [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298638/how-to-add-source-javadoc-for-android-support-v7), I just added in `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module{
        sourceDirs += file("E:\\Android\\sdk\\extras\\android\\support\\v4\\src\\")
        sourceDirs += file("E:\\Android\\sources\\platform_frameworks_support\\v7\\appcompat\\src")
    }
}
```

below `dependencies` section and press "Sync project with Gradle Files"