# How do you attach App Compat documentation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

In Android Studio how do you download and configure Javadoc so that View > External Documentation is available for appcompat classes ?

Right clicking on the appcompat jar in External Libraries leads you to the gradle cache, but this doesn't include a javadoc jar:

`~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0$ find . -name "*" -print
./9865019bbd2d95e41dede3d8ebf964aa93f97766
./9865019bbd2d95e41dede3d8ebf964aa93f97766/appcompat-1.1.0-sources.jar
./83765254bf5e6aa04bb1f35960db460afd70b048
./83765254bf5e6aa04bb1f35960db460afd70b048/appcompat-1.1.0.pom
./351d3409fe51f3d862bd2b1bcc0f3b6ded29460e
./351d3409fe51f3d862bd2b1bcc0f3b6ded29460e/appcompat-1.1.0.aar`

How to download and attach the / a  javadoc jar though?

Comment: appcompat-1.1.0-sources.jar should be correct

Comment: They are correct - but they show you the source code not the external html javadoc

Comment: I believe `View > External Documentation` is the sources, not the Javadoc. But if javadoc was available you'd replace sources with javadoc in the file name

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... View > External Documentation (when available)  shows html javadoc, not sources. For me the command is only available on framework classes afaics. eg. I have 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25' dependency and in External Libraries I see attached slf4j-api-1.7.25-javadoc.jar but the View > External Documentation not available eg. for class org.slf4j.event.EventConstants.
I'll try submitting this as a bug to JetBrains and update the question. Maybe I'm missing something here...

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug... Not all libraries publish their Javadoc

Comment: That would make sense..so you'd need to go through the steps to download androidx sources and then attach...related older question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298638/how-to-add-source-javadoc-for-android-support-v7