# Error while trying to build android when using onesignal ionic 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, onesignal

I am using onesignal for push notications in ionic 3. But when i build the app in android it shows the error

```
Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.jar
```

Comment: Link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/how-do-i-attach-the-android-support-library-source-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```